# Inputting Higher-Order Interaction Terms in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I'm running a logistic model with 10 independent variables and 150,000 observations. I want to fit a model with every interaction term up to the sixth order. However, of course, we know that 10 choose 6 is 210 and I do not want to manually input this model. Is there a command in R which I can use to automatically include every interaction term up to the 6th order?

EDIT: Thanks to Dason for pointing out that there will in fact be 848 parameters total, not just the 210 sixth order interaction terms. Nonetheless, I do want to fit a model with all 848 of these parameters. I know that I can use the polym() function to find all 6th order polynomials of my variables, but that's of course going to be far more parameters than I want just with the interaction terms.

Comment: Note that there are 210 six order interaction terms but if you want all interactions up to six orders that gives you a model with 848 parameters (don't forget to include the main effects, 2nd order interactions, ...).  Are you really sure you want to do this?  Or maybe you might want to spend a little time thinking about the model now to avoid having to spend A LOT of time trying to interpret just what the hell the results will end up meaning.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to mention that there are of course all of the lower-order interaction terms in the model as well. In fact I do want to do this. I am not interested in interpreting the coefficients, I simply want to use the generated model to output a response prediction on a test set.

Comment: I think model `response ~.^6` might work ...

Comment: @BenBolker I'm giving this a shot right now. I don't understand the updating formula well though I've tried to use it before. Could you explain what you think R is actually doing if this approach indeed will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(15000),ncol=10))
m <- model.matrix(~.^6,data=d)
ncol(m) ## 848
```

However, this will not handle higher-order self-interaction terms (e.g. for continuous variables it will have x, y, and x*y, but not x^2 nor y^2), which for continuous variables are arguably necessary for a consistent model.  `.` stands for "all variables in the data frame" (if you put a response variable on the LHS of the formula, it will be excluded from `.`); `^6` says "all interactions up to 6-way". If you want to see what it's doing, check out `colnames(m)`.

I would have guessed this would do it for continuous variables, but it's too big -- I haven't spent too much time thinking about how the number of variables scales with n and p, but it's bad ...

```
m2 <- do.call(polym,c(as.list(d[1:10,1:8]),degree=6))
ncol(m2) ## already 3002 columns
```

By trial and error, I think the number of terms scales as `choose(n+p,p)-1`, so a full 6th-order polynomial model of 10 variables would have 8007 columns ...

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. It was surprisingly difficult to find anything about this anywhere else. Could you clarify what you mean by the last comment: "I would have guessed this would do it for continuous variables, but it's too big -- I haven't spent too much time thinking about how the number of variables scales with n and p, but it's bad ..." ?

Comment: *If* the last incantation is the correct way to generate all terms including self-interactions, then the number of terms for all interactions of `n` variables up to `p`th order increases very rapidly with `n` and `p`, e.g. all 6th-order interactions of 7 variables leads to 1715 terms, of 8 variables leads to 3002 terms, of 9 variables leads to `Cannot allocate vector of size 1.4 Gb` ...

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks for explaining! I'm currently running the logit regression with all 6th-order interaction combinations of my predictors. Crossing my fingers.